# Are back-to-back working holidays in different countries possible?

Tags: working-holiday

Is it possible to do a working holiday visa in one country and then while in that country apply for another one after that so you can just keep working in different countries staying one year in each one?

Comment: You are likely to find you owe taxes to the countries in which you stay and work. If you're a US citizen, you may in addition owe taxes to the US.

Answer (score 6):

The exact requirements differ from country to country and can even depend on your country of citizenship as well as those programmes are often based on bilateral agreements. Some (e.g. [Australia](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/work-holiday-417)) explicitly allow applications online from anywhere outside the country so what you propose could be possible.

On the other hand, some countries do require you to apply in your country of citizenship, making it necessary to go back there before switching to another Working Holiday programme. And even that depends on citizenship: For example, Canadian, Australian, and Colombian citizens can apply for a [French Working Holiday](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/fr_FR/web/france-visas/sejour-prive-de-plus-de-3-mois) from anywhere in the world, all other eligible participants can only do it from their country of citizenship.

Other things will stop you from doing this indefinitely: age thresholds, quotas, finances, insurance requirements, and finally running out of countries to go to (again, depending on your country of citizenship). But it should definitely be possible to organise at least two or three back-to-back stays in different places through Working Holiday scheme. It will however require being very careful regarding the choice and order of countries and investigating the exact rules beforehand.